Obtain avg number of monthly active customers on the web over the past 6 months. An active cust is one that has purchased within the prior 12 mnths
I am seeking help with a complex data modelling problem I am trying to solve. Was wondering if any kind soul with a good SQL expertise is able to help me.
The question is: obtain the average number of monthly active customers on the website over the past 6 months. An active customer is one that has purchased (event_name='Order Receipt) within the prior 12 months.
The table in use has the following structure:

customer_id (int): Unique id of the customer
session_id (int): Unique session id
order_id (int): Unique order id
Event_id (PK - str): Unique id for every click on the website
Event_name (str): Description of the event (can be ‘Product Page View’, ‘Add to Cart’, ‘View Basket’, ‘Order Receipt’)
event_date (TIMESTAMP):  when the user performed the action (in UTC)

The best solution I could come up with so far is this. But I am not confident if its actually considering all the customers throughout a given month
WITH monthly_active_customers AS 
(
    SELECT 
        FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m', TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL month_offset MONTH))) AS month,
        COUNT(DISTINCT IFNULL(
            CAST(customer_id AS STRING), 
            CONCAT('GUEST_', CAST(session_id AS STRING))
        )) AS active_customers
    FROM 
        online-retail-dbt.retail.tblEvent
    CROSS JOIN 
        UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 5)) AS month_offset
    WHERE 
        Event_name = 'Order Receipt'
        AND event_date BETWEEN 
            TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL month_offset MONTH), INTERVAL 12 MONTH)) - INTERVAL 10 HOUR
            AND 
            TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL month_offset MONTH)) - INTERVAL 10 HOUR
    GROUP BY 
        month
    ORDER BY 
        month
)
SELECT 
    ROUND(AVG(active_customers), 2) AS avg_monthly_active_customers
FROM 
    monthly_active_customers;


Hi - please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text (for example, as table create statements). Also, please format your SQL so that it is readable

Also, is a customer active in a month if there is a purchase within 12 months of the first day of the month, the last day of the month, or on any day in the month?

Hi Nick, I have updated the question. I hope it's suitable now (its my first time posting a question).
So the active condition works like this:
For the record I am counting that customer as active, should check if there's any purchase event from that record's event_date till (event_date - 1year)
Does that make sense?

This question would greatly benefit from having sample data and expected outcome

Maybe this could help you. Adjust my Oracle sintax to your sql dialect. Comments in code
Inner SQL - to get months from the table, count distinct customers per month and filter active ones with  a subquery in where clause
Outer SQL - to get average number of active customers for period of last 6 months
SELECT  Round(AVG(cnt_cust_id), 2) as monthly_avg_for_6_months
FROM  ( Select    Trunc(t.event_date, 'mm') as yr_mnth,      -- Trunc() used  to truncate date to the month
                  Count(Distinct t.customer_id) as cnt_cust_id
        From      tbl t 
        Where     t.customer_id IN( Select    Distinct customer_id
                                    From  tbl
                                    Where event_Name = 'Order Receipt' And 
                                          Trunc(event_date) >= Add_Months(Trunc(SYSDATE), -12)
                                   )  
        Group By  Trunc(t.event_date, 'mm')
      )
WHERE   yr_mnth > Add_Months(Trunc(SYSDATE, 'mm'), -6)    -- Add_Months() adds/subtracts months from date




MONTHLY_AVG_FOR_6_MONTHS




1.75



fiddle
